# deserialize integer into a string

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

Is there a way to deserialize an integer into a string ? I need it for compatibility reason.

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace Abc.Test
{
    [JsonSerializable(typeof(OrderInfo), GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Metadata)]
    public partial class OrderInfoContext : JsonSerializerContext
    { }

    public partial class OrderInfo
    {
        public string UserReference { get; set; }
    }
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json = @"{""UserReference"": 123}";  // <---- how having 123 deserialize as a string?

            var s = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(json, OrderInfoContext.Default.OrderInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this json.Deserialize? can you show the code pls?

Comment: I have edited @Serge

Comment: What serializer are you using? I can not compile your code

Comment: It used source generators and net6

Comment: I am sorry but what is a source generator? I never heard before . Can you post a link pls?

Comment: the concept https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-source-generation-modes?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Comment: Thanks, but I still can not compile your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases it can make sense to separate your *serialization objects* (aka DTOs) from your *domain objects*. This give you several benefits:

1. Allow your domain objects to have behavior defined, without affecting serialization.
2. A place to handle any complicated changes to the model without losing backwards compatibility.
3. Allow the serialization objects to fulfill requirements like public setters, without affecting the usage in the rest of the code.

Ex:

```
public class OrderInfoDTO
{ 
    public int UserReference { get; set; }
    public OrderInfo ToModel() => new OrderInfo(UserReference.ToString();
}
public class OrderInfo{
    public string UserReference {get;}
    public OrderInfo(string userReference) => UserReference = userReference;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) on a [property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeProperty.htm). I'll look something like:

```
    public partial class OrderInfo
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(YourCustomConverter))]
        public string UserReference { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I use System.Text.Json and source generators not newtonsoft

Comment: @GuillaumeParis you can use custom converters with STJ.

Comment: Right ; it is more elegant to do JonasH solution